# uv light dc current

Tags: current, dc, uv

I am working on a project which uses UV rays to kill bacteria in water and make it safe to drink. The people who would use this do not have access to an AC source, so I need the UV Light source to be powered by a DC.

I have tried current convertors but they make the product highly inefficient. If anyone knows of a company that created DC powered UV light beams, it would be of great help to me.

Comment: 1) Asking for product recommendations is **Off topic**. 2) depending on how the UV light is created it might use DC (internally in the UV source) already. 3) What kind of DC voltage and current is available and how much power do you think your UV source needs to be?

Comment: Did you know that germicidal LEDs are a thing these days?  Google it.

Answer (score 2):

You can take the circuit that powers a fluorescent lamp from DC (eg. a camping light) and replace the lamp with a germicidal one.

The two types of lamps are electrically the same- the difference is that the one designed for visible light is coated with phosphor that emits white light and it has an envelope made of glass that tends to block UV-C 253.7 nm light from the mercury discharge.

UV-C LEDs are available now, but tend to be quite expensive.

Comment: I was about to write something like this, about the \$2536.5\mathring{A}\$ mercury line and that LEDs (those I've had a chance to apply to an Ocean Optics Spectro set up for the right range) just haven't got much to work with there, or nearby even. Do you know of any manufacturer I can look up for an LED with any significant emissions anywhere near 254nm? I don't know of one and would love to hear of an option -- regardless of price. Most common materials block it, anyway. I use fused silica or sapphire to pass the light. Gets blocked far too easy.

Comment: @jonk 10-15mW of 280nm in a TO-3 for [a mere $1,400](http://www.qphotonics.com/catalog/Deep-UV-high-power-LED-lamp-10-15mW-280nm-UVCLEAN280-15-p-791.html). There are doubtless cheaper ones. I assume it has a quartz window like the old EPROMs.

Comment: Thanks. That's still got *almost nothing* left anywhere near 254nm. But it does have something between 280nm and 290nm. Without reading a research paper on the topic, most generic discussions about germicidals assume 254nm application. So I need to find a paper analyzing effectiveness on bacteria over wavelength (and that probably varies with the bacteria, too) to know any better about this particular unit. Wow that is expensive!! (DNA has high absorption at 254nm.)

Comment: @jonk UV-C is 100nm-290nm so it's within that band, but no it's not got much near the mercury line. Internet says maximum absorption of DNA is at 260nm.  Is calling it "germicidal" false advertising if it doesn't disrupt DNA?

Comment: I picked up this [UV absorbance DNA quantization curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwZdI.png). I've gotten so I almost never, ever assume that advertizing is true, anymore. Let's see: VW green, clean diesel? Etc. Etc. Etc. Verify everything should be the rule, I think.

Comment: @jonk So does that mean that 1.5mW @t 280nm is about equivalent to 1mW at 260nm? hmm.

Comment: It's the integrated absorbed energy that counts, ignorant of more specific knowledge to the contrary. I'd probably digitize those curves and apply them to the emissions of various lamps' outputs in watts per cm^2 against this curve to work out the absorbed energy per unit time for comparison. Not sure how that would come out. However, without independent and well-reasoned effectiveness testing, a marketer telling me they have a germicidal LED would fall on deaf ears today. It does look as though it could be used, but how long in similar circumstances for equal results? I don't know.

Comment: @jonk [255nm 1mW UV LED](https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=LED255J) - compared to the $1500 one, those are dirt cheap at only $600.

Comment: @TomCarpenter $/mW is ~5x higher but it's shorter wavelength.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany ahh true. Misread the other one as 1 to 1.5mW. But anyway.